# How to create a bulleted list using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, jspdf

I was wondering how I can make a bulleted list in jsPDF. I have prepared a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-oukdf) that uses the old (and now also deprecated `fromHTML` function). Unfortunately, as you can see in the sandbox, it doesn't render the bullet points anymore. In their docs they do have a [html](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html) callback function, which also doesn't work. In both cases, the list gets rendered, just not the bullet points.

Now I am aware I can use `html2canvas` to produce a screenshot of a certain `div`, however, I really need it to be text and not a screenshot.

Does anyone know if it is still possible to make a bulleted list using jsPDF? If not, what are some alternatives I can maybe look at?

Comment: have you looked at [this](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/html2pdf/lists.html)?

Comment: Yeah I have, but there they just create an `iframe` with a `datauristring` as the source of that iframe. That also won't give me the 'text' bullet points I need, right?

Comment: I didn't investigate it in depth, it was just a suggestion, so I'm afraid I don't know. Worth a shot